# REact warning when rendering inline jsx instead of imported class

Tags: reactjs

In the following code I get a warning if the `default` case in the `select` runs:

```
import React, { Component, propTypes } from 'react';
import Bar from './Bar/Bar';
import Baz from './Baz/Baz';

export default class Foo extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    mode: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    basePath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    let Response;
    switch (this.props.mode) {
      case 'init':
        Response = Bar;
        break;
      case 'edit':
        Response = Baz;
        break;
      default:
        Response = <div></div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Response basePath={this.props.basePath} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The warning:

```
warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Foo`.
```

How should I be creating an empty `div` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it so that `Response` is a function:

```
default:
  Response = () => <div></div>
```

React expects a component, not an element (i.e. component instance). Here Response will be a functional stateless component, and your warning should be gone.